# Python Subprocess Popen Parallelization

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

### Objective

- a process (.exe) with multiple input arguments
- Multiple files. For each the above mentioned process shall be executed
- I want to use python to parallelize the process
- I am using subprocess.Popen to create the processes and afterwards keep a maximum of N parallel processes.
- For testing purposes, I want to parallelize a simple script like "cmd timeout 5".

### State of work

```
import subprocess 

count = 10
parallel = 2

processes = []
for i in range(0,count):
    while (len(processes) >= parallel):
        for process in processes:
            if (process.poll() is None):
                processes.remove(process)
                break
    process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c timeout 5"])
    processes.append(process)

[...]
```

I read somewhere that a good approach for checking if a process is running would be *is not None* like shown in the code.

### Question

I am somehow struggling to set it up correctly, especially the Popen([...]) part. In some cases, all processes are executed without considering the maximum parallel count and in other cases, it doesnt work at all.

I guess that there has to be a part where the process is closed if finished.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have a better time using the built-in multiprocessing module to manage the subprocesses running your tasks.

The reason I've wrapped the command in a dict is that `imap_unordered` (which is faster than `imap` but doesn't guarantee ordered execution since any worker process can grab any job – whether that's okay for you is your business problem) doesn't have a `starmap` alternative, so it's easier to unpack a single "job" within the callable.

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess


def run_command(job):
    # TODO: add other things here?
    subprocess.check_call(job["command"])


def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as p:
        jobs = [{"command": ["cmd", "/c timeout 5"]} for x in range(10)]
        for result in p.imap_unordered(run_command, jobs):
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for my original purpose. However, I cant figure out how to a simple command script like "timeout 5"... but OK :)